# In Kivy, how to make a bitmap, point-clickable and (proportionally) resizable?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to display a bitmap in Kivy, and give it several properties, some of which seem to be mutually-exclusive. It should be:

- point-clickable (able to find point-coordinates, not just a button-click)
- resizable
- maintain proportion when resized

It's the last item that seems to be a problem. I can make a bitmap that is basically a Button-type object, and it's point-clickable - but it's a fixed size. Or I can make a "stretchy" bitmap, which will resize when the Window resizes. But - either it's proportion shifts, or the "bitmap" section of the Widget display in correct proportion, but there's a non-proportional component to the Widget, that can be clicked.

The first set is "button" mode, the second is "stretch" mode.

[image: button-mode widget]

[image: stretch-mode widget]

In the stretch-mode, the actual display *bitmap* does both resize, and maintain a proportional size. However, the *Image* Widget that displays it, is resizing non-proportionally. (So the `keep_ratio` option, applies to the bitmap that is displayed, but not the actual Widget object.) Which would be fine, but the entire Widget is clickable, and I haven't found a way to determine where a clicked point is, relative to the bitmap.

I can think of semi-solutions, like forcing Window resizes to be proportional, changing width/height as needed to match, but that's fairly messy. It seems like there should be some way of doing it, using Kivy objects/properties, but I haven't found one yet.

Actual code sample. To run in "button" mode,

```
  KIVY_NO_ARGS=1 python show_bitmap.py -b
```

```
import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
hex_bmp = 'basic_hexes.png'
hex_bmp_size = (456, 292)

stretch_params = {'source': hex_bmp,  # Bitmap is stretchable, but click-region is wrong
                  'allow_stretch': True,
                  'keep_ratio': True,
                  'pos': (110, 110),
                  'size': hex_bmp_size,
                  'size_hint': (0.5, 0.5),
                  }
button_params = {'source': hex_bmp,  # Behaves like a Button, with regard to click-region
                 'allow_stretch': True,
                 'keep_ratio': True,
                 'pos': (110, 110),
                 'size': hex_bmp_size,
                 'size_hint': (None, None),
                 }
new_params = stretch_params

class VariableImage(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**new_params, **kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_resize=self.on_window_resize)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5)
            self.bg_rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f"*** Clicked VariableImage, pos: {touch.pos}")

    def on_window_resize(self, window, width, height):
        self.bg_rect.size = self.size

class TopBoxLayout(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, initial_window_size, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.bg_rect = None
        self.size = initial_window_size
        self.label_2 = Label(text='WTF?', pos_hint={'top': 1}, size_hint=(1.0, 0.1))
        self.add_widget(self.label_2)
        self.back_picture = VariableImage()
        self.add_widget(self.back_picture)
        self.setup_background()
        Window.bind(on_resize=self.on_window_resize)

    def setup_background(self):
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9)
            self.bg_rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        with self.canvas.after:
            Color(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
            self.target_rect = Rectangle(pos=(100, 100), size=(10, 10))

    def on_window_resize(self, window, width, height):
        self.bg_rect.pos = self.pos
        self.bg_rect.size = self.size

class canvasMain(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (700, 450)
        self.root = TopBoxLayout(Window.size)
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '-b':
        new_params = button_params
    canvasMain().run()
```

Comment: There have been times, when I'm writing out a question, cutting down the code, etc, that I've found the answer in the process ("rubber-ducking" FTW). This is not one of those times - Kivy has been kicking my butt... My mental-model of it, is *just* a bit off, and nothing works like I expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is to make sure that the `VariableImage` instance keeps its ratio matching the ratio of the bitmap. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

kv = '''
<TopBoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
        Rectangle:
            pos: 100, 100
            size: 10, 10
    Label:
        text: 'WTF?'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint: (1.0, 0.1)
    VariableImage:
        id: vi
        size_hint: None, None
        # size: 0.5 * root.width, 0.5 * root.width / self.image_ratio  # does the same as the `on_size()` method
<VariableImage>:
    source: 'basic_hexes.png'
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: True
    pos: (110, 110)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
'''

class VariableImage(Image):

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f"*** Clicked VariableImage, pos: {touch.pos}")

class TopBoxLayout(RelativeLayout):
    def on_size(self, instance, new_size):
        vi = self.ids.vi
        # adjust size of VariableImage based on layout width
        # a more complicated logic can be used, like keeping size with layout size
        vi.size = 0.5 * self.width, 0.5 * self.width / vi.image_ratio

class canvasMain(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (700, 450)
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return TopBoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    canvasMain().run()
```

This uses the `kivy` language to do some simplification. The line in the `kv`:

```
size: 0.5 * root.width, 0.5 * root.width / self.image_ratio
```

keeps the ratio of the `VariableImage` the same as the bitmap ratio (if uncommented). The `on_size()` method of `TopBoxLayout` will do exactly the same thing, but is easier to use for more complicated logic.

You don't need both approaches. One or the other can be deleted.

Comment: And that was a very fast answer. It would appear you're a kivy *guru*. :)

Comment: Interesting. I was working on something similar (pure python-code, no kv-language), but my code was a lot more complicated, I was computing ratios by hand, for instance. This raises several questions. First, presumably the "0.5" was taken from the `size_hint`, and would change accordingly? And presumably `image_ratio` is the original ratio, so I might want to store it?

Comment: The `image_ratio` is a property of the actual `texture` of the `Image`, which is the ratio of the actual `source`, and will not change as long as the `source` is not changed. The `0.5` was taken from the original `size_hint` and can be modified as you see fit.

Comment: That mostly works, thanks. (As you noted, it needs more logic, this only handles width-changes). But I do have one more question - this might even be worth a separate Question, not sure. Mainly, what is `on_size()` all about? I can find essentially zero documentation on what it does, only a few sparse references to it, in the docs. Is it deprecated? I experimented a bit - it appears auto-bound to the Layout, so doesn't need `bind()` like `on_resize` - clearly there's some magic going on. And I couldn't find it anywhere in the object-hierarchy, even looking at the source-code. Weird...

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-on-propname).